# I have try list down past 20 years in dropdown list. But not able to display it as range where Year to Year form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got past 20 years from current year. but currently i want it to show as year to year .
For example: 1992 - 1999 
             1999 - 2002
             2003 - 2015

Here is my code.

```js
function populatedropdown(yearfield) {
  var today = new Date(),
      yearfield = document.getElementById(yearfield),
      beforeYears = 20
      thisyear = today.getFullYear();
  
  for (var year = thisyear-beforeYears, index = 0; 
           index <= beforeYears; 
           index++, year++) {
    yearfield.options[index] = new Option(year, year);
  }
  yearfield.value = thisyear;
    //select today's year
}

//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload = function() {
  populatedropdown("yeardropdown")
}
```

```html
<td><select id="yeardropdown"/></td>
```

This is the ideal output that i wish to have it 
[image: year to year]

Comment: I've removed the [tag:java] tag from your question because I don't see that it has anything to do with Java programming. Please do let me know if I was mistaken in doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if I did, it's easier than what you already have:

```js
function populatedropdown(yearfield) {
  var today = new Date(),
      yearfield = document.getElementById(yearfield),
      beforeYears = 20,
      thisYear = today.getFullYear(),
      firstYear = thisYear - beforeYears,
      yearRange = firstYear + ' - ' + thisYear;
  
  yearfield.options[0] = new Option(yearRange, yearRange);
  yearfield.value = yearRange;
}

//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload = function() {
  populatedropdown("yeardropdown")
}
```

```html
<select id="yeardropdown"/>
```

---

**Update**

Since you've updated your question, here is the proposed solution I have:

```js
(function(d) {
  d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
        totalYears = 20,
        firstYear = currentYear - totalYears;    
    
    var fromYear = d.getElementById('fromYear'),
        toYear = d.getElementById('toYear');
    
    for (var i = firstYear; i <= currentYear; i++) {
      var opt = d.createElement('option');
      opt.value = i;
      opt.textContent = i;
      
      fromYear.appendChild(opt);
      toYear.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
    }
    
    toYear.value = currentYear;
    
    /* if you don't want to disable the impossible selections, remove the code below */
    disableYears();
    
    fromYear.addEventListener('change', disableYears);
    toYear.addEventListener('change', disableYears);
    
    function disableYears(e) {
      [].forEach.call(fromYear.querySelectorAll('option'), function(opt, i) {
        opt.disabled = opt.value > toYear.value;
      });
      
      [].forEach.call(toYear.querySelectorAll('option'), function(opt, i) {
        opt.disabled = opt.value < fromYear.value;
      });
    }
    /* if you don't want to disable the impossible selections, remove the code above */
  });
})(document);
```

```html
<select id='fromYear'></select>
<select id='toYear'></select>
```

Comment: I have try to edit and update my question. I wish to choose year instead of show the years together.

Comment: what if using if else to loop for next few line of year?
eg : 1992 - 1994
       1994 - 2001
       2001 - 2015